# My Ubuntu won't install g++ but will install g++ 4.6 and g++ 4.7

Tags: apt, software-installation

Could someone please tell me a sure-way of getting g++ and g++4.7 on to my Ubuntu? I have spent the whole day trying lots of sudo apt-get and nothing has worked.

When compiling from the IDE I am missing g++ as I get the compiler error:

> “make[2]: g++: Command not found”

If I do:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config g++
```

it returns:

```
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for g++.
```

If I do:

```
g++ --version
```

it returns:

```
The program 'g++' can be found in the following packages:
 * g++
 * pentium-builder
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

I already have gcc 4.8 but I need g++ 4.7 (and possibly 4.8 if someone could advise me how I can download that?) because my code (which I did manage to compile with 4.7 earlier) is giving a compiler bug internal error.

(I havent been able to list every command I tried as there's been so many). There must be a way which definitely works

EDIT:

Have run to get g++ 4.6 so now when I call the g++ --version I get 4.6 showing. I then tried sudo apt-get install g++-4.7 to "upgrade" to 4.7 but this seemed to lose my g++ because I couldnt do g++ --version afterwards. I reverted back to 4.6. How can I upgrade to 4.7 **and I really need to know how to get g++ 4.8**?

Comment: I have- which is how I originally found a g++ internal compiler error... which is what lead me to try and update to 4.8 (which now seems to have made my g++ disappear).

Answer (score 3):

If I have to guess, I will say that somehow your `g++` symbolic link got damaged. A reinstallation of the `g++` package should fix the issue:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install g++
```

Or, if you like doing things manually (you should try the above method first), you could:

#### If you have 4.6

```
sudo ln -i -s /usr/bin/g++-4.6 /usr/bin/g++
```

#### If you have 4.7

```
sudo ln -i -s /usr/bin/g++-4.7 /usr/bin/g++
```

#### If you have 4.8

```
sudo ln -i -s /usr/bin/g++-4.8 /usr/bin/g++
```

Comment: I will try the above now. I'd like to say thanks for continuing to help me- I really appreciate it.

Comment: OK I tried the --reinstall command you wrote above and it worked to the extent that if I do g++ --version it now says I am using 4.6. WHen I try to see all versions I have via sudo update-alternatives --config g++ it doesn't work, still says no alternatives. Would you be able to tell me how I can install g++ 4.8 because I think I require this to get around the internal compiler bug I discovered when using 4.7?

Comment: Worked out whats happening. When I go to install g++4.7 I seem to lose my g++ altogether. I use: sudo apt-get install g++-4.7 after your command...

Comment: As far as I know, the gcc-4.x and g++-4.x packages do not automatically add themselves to the `update-alternatives` mechanism. You can add them manually using `update-alternatives --install` as described here --> http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2177404&p=12802113#post12802113 however I'm reluctant to post that as an answer since there are likely good reasons why that is not done by default. Or you can create the appropriate symlinks manually as described by @Braiam .

Comment: @steeldriver you beat it to me :(

Comment: @mezamorphic see steeldriver comment above

Comment: @steeldriver When I try sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.7 50 it says update-alternatives: error: alternative g++ can't be master: it is a slave of gcc

Comment: Sorry I have no experience of dealing with the master/slave setup, maybe @Braiam will be able to help

Comment: @mezamorphic can you ask another question. Comments are not the way to solve problems. Or better yet, use symlinks instead as I have shown in my answer.